# Count for distinct values for a certain id in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am learning MongoDB aggregation for our data analysis. The sample dataset is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8fa906cd5591004c2db5f9"), "id" : 49893861, "cate_id" : "81614" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8fa906cd5591004c2db602"), "id" : 49893861, "cate_id" : "1102" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8fa906cd5591004c2db606"), "id" : 49893861, "cate_id" : "1102" }
```

The desired result should be:

```
{
  "id": 49893861,
  "categories": [
    {
      "cate_id": "1102",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "cate_id": "81614",
      "count": 1
    },
  ]
}
```

I am wondering how to achieve this using the correct MongoDB aggregation framework command. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages here. First with `id` and `cate_id`  and `count` the number of documents **and** then second with `id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "id": { "$toLong": "$id" },
      "cate_id": "$cate_id"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.id",
    "categories": {
      "$push": {
        "cate_id": "$_id.cate_id",
        "count": "$count"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this gave me the desired results!